Unitary retrieving game
My question is about the optimal strategies for retrieving/estimating an $n$-qubit black-box unitary $U$ using sequential single-shot measurements. Each shot is selected from a finite set of what I refer to as 'Pauli measurement modes' (see the next paragraph). The choice of the next measurement mode is conditioned on the previous choices made and the results of the corresponding measurements.
A Pauli mode is specified by a (i) chain of single-qubit rotations applied to the state before passing the state $\vert 0 \rangle^n$ into the black box, so that the incoming state, $\vert \boldsymbol{s} \rangle = \bigotimes_{i=1}^n \vert s_i \rangle$, is a product state with each qubit being in one of the six basis eigenstates, $\vert s_i \rangle \in \lbrace \vert \pm x_i \rangle, \vert \pm y_i \rangle, \vert \pm z_i \rangle \rbrace$. The state $U \vert \boldsymbol{s} \rangle$ is then measured in different Pauli bases, $b_j \in \lbrace x_j, y_j, z_j \rbrace$. A single Pauli measurement mode therefore is specified by the vector $\boldsymbol{p} = (\boldsymbol{s}, \boldsymbol{b})$, where $\boldsymbol{s} = \lbrace s_1, \ldots, s_n \rbrace$ and $\boldsymbol{b} = \lbrace b_1, \ldots, b_n \rbrace$. The total number of measurement modes is $(6 \cdot 3)^n$.
Now, at step $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots, \ell_{\text{stop}}$, we can choose a Pauli mode, $\lbrace \boldsymbol{s}, \boldsymbol{b} \rbrace_{\ell}$, perform the measurement, and record the outcome, a binary string $t^{\ell}_1 t^{\ell}_2 \ldots t^{\ell}_n$. We then have to choose the next Pauli mode or stop. There are two different situations, $\ell_{\text{stop}} < \infty$ and $\ell_{\text{stop}} = \infty$ (in this case, we can stop whenever we want).
There is an ambiguity concerning the quantifier of the retrieval accuracy. Unfortunately, the space of unitaries does not admit metrics (as far as I know). Let's assume, for example, that we use average fidelity as the quantifier (though anything else can be used).
The question is: What is the best strategy, in terms of accuracy of retrieval (if $\ell_{\text{stop}} = \infty$) and/or the number of queries (if $\ell_{\text{stop}} < \infty$)?
Let's also reduce the setup to the minimal one, $n = 1$. In this case, for example, every $U$ can be parameterized with four real numbers, $\lbrace \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \rbrace$, with $U = e^{i \alpha} R_x(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta)$. Thus, the retrieved $U_r$ will be represented by a list of four real numbers, $\lbrace \alpha_r, \beta_r, \gamma_r, \delta_r \rbrace$.
In this case, at the first step, we can choose randomly any of the eighteen Pauli modes. For example, assume we always start with $\lbrace +z, z \rbrace$. Now, if the outcome of the measurement is $0$, what is the next step? What mode should we use as the second choice? And what if the outcome is $1$?
Any suggestions, even vague ones, would be appreciated because I have no idea how to proceed.
